# Linux perf symbol truncation

Tags: c++, linux, perf

I have two problems related to the display of symbols when running `perf report` after `perf record -g`, so I wanted to see if anyone can help me with them.  I'm running this on a C++ executable which uses a lot of templates so there are very long type names.

1. When I run `perf report`, I can't scroll the symbol name left and right to see the whole thing.  Pressing the left and right arrows just scrolls the rows not in the currently selected stack trace, and even then I can't see the full symbol name.
2. If I run `perf report > foo.txt`, the symbol name is still truncated to 1023 characters.  I can run it with `--no-demangle` and then run that through `c++filt`, but it seems like this shouldn't be necessary.

Does anyone know how to solve this within `perf`?

Comment: First of all, please mention the system details - as to which linux version are you using and the system architecture. Can you also show us what is the output that you get from `perf report` ? Symbol truncation does happen in `perf` but unless you provide us with your test case outputs, it is just a bit hard to answer.

Comment: Brandon, check output of `perf script` and/or `pref script -D`. They may have different truncate settings and will also show instruction addresses, which you can combine with `nm` or `objdump` or `addr2line` tools to get symbol name.

Comment: @ArnabjyotiKalita This happens with `perf report` and `perf report --stdio` every time with long symbols with every version I've ever tried across multiple distros on x86-64. It's pretty simple, run perf report on  binary with a symbol of 1000+ characters (easy with C++ templates) and see that after a little while you can't keep scrolling right to see the full name.